# how to remove leading 0 from column

Tags: r, regex, str-replace

I am new to `R` and would like to know how to remove leading `0`s from a determinate column in a database. 
This is the column I have in my `df`.

```
questionn
SI001
SI002
SI003
SI010
```

and I would like to get something like

```
questionn
1
2
3
10
```

I have tried something like this but it doesn't work because of the `SI010`

```
library(stringr)
df$questionn <- str_replace_all(df$questionn, 'SQ0', '')
```

**data**

```
df <- data.frame(questionn=c("SI001","SI002","SI003","SI010"),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Those aren't leading zeros.  Is there a pattern to this data?  Is `SI` always there?  Is it always followed by three digits?  Need more info.

Comment: You can simply do `as.numeric(gsub('\\D+', '', df$questionn))`

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
as.numeric(str_replace_all(df$questionn,"SI0",""))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove all characters that are not digits then convert as numeric:

```
as.numeric(gsub("\\D","",df$questionn))
[1]  1  2  3 10
```

or `as.numeric(str_replace_all(df$questionn,"\\D",""))` for same output.

Answer (score 0):

```
substr(gsub("SI", "", question$question),
         regexpr("[^0]",gsub("SI", "", question$question)),
         nchar(gsub("SI", "", question$question)))
```

Produces:

```
 "1"  "2"  "3"  "10"
```

The first thing you do is strip out the SI, to get the data in a format of having leading zeros.